# Updating iOS app: update name and keywords only, no binary

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes

I want to update name and keywords of my app. That data can be changed in iTunes Connect only. Maybe I will update screenshots or some other data from iTunes Connect.

But should I post new app build? I see the form of new build but is that necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sffsf some of fields can be edited any time without submitting new build. However in your case even editing description or changing images needs to add new build and go through approval process again. 
Please see below link last section describes the update process in detail ( read *fields which can be updated without submitting new build )

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html